# If ignoring repeated measures data in kruskal wallis test, is it assumption violated?

Tags: anova, nonparametric

This data is repeated measures data and groups are included.(Mixed Design)

I want to Non-parametric test between Group effect (Kruskal-Wallis Test) and Within effect(Friedman Test) separatedly. (Don't want Parametric Test. and Friedman Test is testing Later.)

Like testing 'difference between Grand mean effect' & 'difference between Column mean effect'.

Data is Stacked by repeated measures.

If ignoring repeated measures data in Kruskal-Wallis test, Is it assumption violated? (Assumption: Random Sample or Independent Sample)

My data is below here.

```
# From Table 1 of Deal et al (1979):  Role of respiratory heat exchange in production of exercise-induced asthma.  J Appl Physiol 46:467-475

dat <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
temp1 = c(74.5,75.5,68.9,57,78.3,54,72.5,80.8),
    temp2 = c(81.5,84.6,71.6,61.3,84.9,62.8,68.3,89.9),
    temp3 = c(83.6,70.6,55.9,54.1,64,63,67.8,83.2),
    temp4 = c(68.6,87.3,61.9,59.2,62.2,58,71.5,83),
    temp5 = c(73.1,73,60.5,56.6,60.1,56,65,85.7),
    temp6 = c(79.4,75,61.8,58.8,78.7,51.5,67.7,79.6))

# stacked Data
dat.s <- stack(dat[,-1])
SUBJNO <- rep(seq(1,8),6)
GROUP <- rep(rep(seq(1,4),2),6)
dat.s2 <- cbind(dat.s,SUBJNO)
dat.s2 <- cbind(dat.s,GROUP)
head(dat.s2)
# Kruskall-Wallis Test
# I think this is like difference between grand mean
# Is it violated assumption 'Random Samplle (or Independent Sample'?
kruskal.test(values ~ GROUP, data = dat.s2)

# Below codes are supporting my think... but just in this sample
# I'm not good at mathmetical thinking...help!
kruskal.test(values ~ GROUP, data = dat.s2[dat.s2$GROUP %in% c(1,2),])
kruskal.test(values ~ GROUP, data = dat.s2[dat.s2$GROUP %in% c(1,3),])
kruskal.test(values ~ GROUP, data = dat.s2[dat.s2$GROUP %in% c(1,4),])
kruskal.test(values ~ GROUP, data = dat.s2[dat.s2$GROUP %in% c(2,3),])
kruskal.test(values ~ GROUP, data = dat.s2[dat.s2$GROUP %in% c(2,4),])
kruskal.test(values ~ GROUP, data = dat.s2[dat.s2$GROUP %in% c(3,4),])
mean(dat.s2$values[dat.s2$GROUP==1])  # 1st Biggest mean
mean(dat.s2$values[dat.s2$GROUP==2])  # 3rd Biggest mean
mean(dat.s2$values[dat.s2$GROUP==3])  # 4th Biggest mean
mean(dat.s2$values[dat.s2$GROUP==4])  # 2nd Biggest mean

# I think this is like difference between column mean.
# maybe this is not violated assumption (Random Sample or Independent Sample)
kruskal.test(values ~ GROUP, data = dat.s2[dat.s2$ind=='temp1',])
kruskal.test(values ~ GROUP, data = dat.s2[dat.s2$ind=='temp2',])
kruskal.test(values ~ GROUP, data = dat.s2[dat.s2$ind=='temp3',])
kruskal.test(values ~ GROUP, data = dat.s2[dat.s2$ind=='temp4',])
kruskal.test(values ~ GROUP, data = dat.s2[dat.s2$ind=='temp5',])
kruskal.test(values ~ GROUP, data = dat.s2[dat.s2$ind=='temp6',])
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes assumptions are strongly violated.  The Kruskal-Wallis test assumes independent observations.  And note that it doesn't test means, and comparing all means with the grand mean is not the best way of thinking about contrasts.

Comment: @Frank Harrell I'm really grateful for your answer. Thanks.